# Using alias by executing command remotely with ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, alias

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
ttmp="SUCCESS"
alias aliased_command='echo $ttmp'
```

I can use alias remotely by adding the above lines to .bashrc file.

```
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER aliased_command
SUCCESS
```

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt

`expand_aliases` option allows for non-interactive shells to use aliases.

However, when I run:

```
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER echo $-
himBH
```

it seems that running a remote command through ssh is using an interactive shell.(`i` is contained)

Is this right?

If right, why does this need expand_aliases option?

If wrong, if `ssh SERVER COMMAND` uses a non-interactive shell, why does `ssh MYSERVER COMMAND` read `.bashrc` file of MYSERVER when [a non-interactive shell doesn't read `.bashrc` file](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)?

cf) quoting command results a different output

```
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER 'echo $-'
hBc
```

Any link, comment appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two aspects:

#### 1. Quoting

Unquoted `$-` is expanded by your *local* shell. Note the local `ssh` can build shell code (to run on the remote side) from multiple arguments it gets. When you did `ssh MYSERVER echo $-`, the remote shell got `echo himBH`. The `himBH` string came from your local shell. When you did `ssh MYSERVER 'echo $-'`, the remote shell got `echo $-`.

See [*How to execute complex command line over ssh*](https://superuser.com/q/1533956/432690) and my answer there. I won't repeat everything here. The most important thing:

> To be in control of what the remote shell will get as `$command_line_built_by_ssh`, you need to understand, predict and mastermind the parsing and interpreting that happens before. You need to craft your local command, so *after* the local shell and `ssh` digest it, it becomes the exact `$command_line…` you want to execute on the remote side.

A good method is to pass the exact (remote) command to the local `ssh` as a single argument. This is what you did by `ssh MYSERVER 'echo $-'` and the single-quotes prevented local expansion. The `$-` was unquoted in the context of the remote shell.

As a result `hBc` came *from the remote shell*. The remote shell was not interactive.

#### 2. Bash tries to be smart

About non-interactive shell sourcing `.bashrc`, see [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690):

> Twist number 2: Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by a SSH server. If Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it does read and execute commands from `~/.bashrc`.

You linked to the [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). What I'm talking about is under "Invoked by remote shell daemon". There are more twists, see the full linked answer.